# Get next member that matches criteria mdx

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am attempting to return a measure two periods from the current member on the time dimension however I need to only include periods that match a certain criteria (Is_Business_Day = true)

I currently have:

```
(
    [Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER.NEXTMEMBER.NEXTMEMBER, 
    [Measures].[SOME MEASURE]
)
```

Which accurately returns the value of the measure two members in the future, but now I need to additionally apply the filter, but can't quite figure out how to do so.

**EDIT:**

My thinking is that I would have to do something similar to the following

```
(
    Head(
        exists(
            [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.NextMember:[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Lead(6),
            [Date].[Is Business Day].&[True]
        ),
        2
    ).item(1),
    [Measures].[SOME MEASURE]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both hierarchies, `[Date].[Calendar]` and `[Date].[Is Business Day]` are in teh same dimension, you can rely on SSAS "Autoexists" which is usually faster than `Exists`. Hence,

```
((([Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050718].nextmember : null )
  *
  { [Date]..Item(0) }
 ).Item(0)
 ,[Measures].[SOME MEASURE]
)
```

The `: null` construct builds a set to the end of the `Date` level, i. e. to the last day contained in the attribute.

Cross joining with `[Date].[Is Business Day].&[True]` automatically restricts the set to those members that co-exist in the dimension (the magic of autoexists).

And `.Item(0)` extracts the first tuple. In case you need a tuple not of the date, the `.Item(0)`, and the measure member, but just of the date and the measure in your context, apply another `Item(0)` after the first. This would extract the first member from the tuple.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know about autoexists. Still quite new to MDX and SSAS as a whole. Works as expected.